# Complete email domain after @ symbol in AngularJS input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a function that will automatically detect if a user has typed '@' symbol and will autocomplete the field with corporate domain. There might be multiple fields on the page that's why I don't want to hardcode theirs models (e.g. `$scope.user.email`).
Here' what I got so far:

```
<input ng-model="user.email" ng-keyup="autocompleteEmail($event);">
```

And corresponding controller code:

```
$scope.autocompleteEmail = function($event) {
    if (($event.keyCode === 48 || $event.keyCode === 50) && $event.srcElement.value.slice(-1) === "@") {
      // @ symbol is typed - completing email
      $event.srcElement.value += "mycompany.com";
    }
}
```

Autocompletion works fine but the problem appears as soon as I try to submit the form with this new value - it doesn't take into account **mycompany.com** domain that I've added automatically. And request that is being sent has `user.email = test@`.

How can I achieve this autocomplete functionality with AngularJS?

Comment: You could just keep track of all the models for the fields you want to auto-complete in an object or array and just update the proper model from there on the controller side. Due to the two-way binding that should also update the view.

Answer (score 1):

To make it as generic as possible, you could go with a directive approach. See this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/uPlQjmXIHeI6EwBcucx5?p=preview)

```
myApp.directive('completeEmailDomain', function(){  
 return {
    scope: {
       domain: '@',
       email: '='
    },
     restrict: 'E',
     template: '<input ng-model="email" ng-keyup="autoCompleteEmail($event);" />',
     link: function($scope, elem, attr) {
          $scope.autoCompleteEmail = function($event){
            console.log($scope.email);
            if (($event.keyCode === 48 || $event.keyCode === 50) && $event.srcElement.value.slice(-1) === "@") {
              $scope.email += $scope.domain;
            }
          }
     } 
 }; 
});
```

In there, I created a directive called "complete-email-domain". It takes in the domain and the email and will automatically update the model once the user enters a '@'.  This should be completely re-usable and should scope the actual handling of changing the value to the new directive.

Perhaps an improvement would be to just store the domain on the user object and pass along the user to the directive. Then you can just access the "domain" and "email" properties in a very similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `user` variable as a parameter in the method so it can be reusable:

```
 <input ng-model="user.email" ng-keyup="autocompleteEmail($event, user);">
```

And take care of that parameter:

```
  $scope.autocompleteEmail = function($event, user) {
       if (($event.keyCode === 48 || $event.keyCode === 50) &&        $event.srcElement.value.slice(-1) === "@") {
  // @ symbol is typed - completing email
  user.email  += "mycompany.com";
}
```

Try this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YXyHhfouTDD5RIhZx1ln?p=preview)

Comment: how would this solve the problem? can you elaborate on the concept?

Comment: just exchange the lines I said... and let me know if it works

Comment: if you are setting the value of the input via jquery, angular can't know about it, so the changes won't propagate. You need to use angular structure to change models, so angular can keep track of it

Comment: I can't use `$scope` variables as far as there might be multiple inputs that need this autocompletion and the function should be generic to work for each of these inputs.   P.S. I've updated question for others to have this information in mind. Thank you.

Comment: then update the question with your expected behavior

Comment: @LucasRodriguez, I know this but it's not elegant. It's the same solution as before - I will need to pass `ng-model` to each call of the function and I don't want to do this. I need generic solution. I'm sure it exists but I'm missing something. Maybe usind directive can solve the issue...